# How to modify the format of JSON data to achieve the result in a specific format - Select Options Group Angular Material Dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to populate options group in Angular material dropdown - similar to the following article -
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

I need my JSON data to be in this format -

```
[
{
year: '2020',
plan: [
  {planValue: 'Plan1 - 2020',  planName: 'Plan1 - 2020'}  
  {planValue: 'Plan2 - 2020',  planName: 'Plan2 - 2020'}
]
},
{
year: '2021',
plan: [
{planValue: 'Plan3 - 2021',  planName: 'Plan3 - 2021'} 
]
}
]
```

This is the output of my current code - How do I modify it to achieve the above.

```
[
{
year: '2020',
plan: [
  'Plan1 - 2020',        
  'Plan2 - 2020'
]
},
{
year: '2021',
plan: ['Plan3 - 2021']
}
]
```

```js
myArray = [{
    "PlanName": "Plan1 - 2020",
    "Year": "2020"
  },
  {
    "PlanName": "Plan2 - 2020",
    "Year": "2020"
  },
  {
    "PlanName": "Plan3 - 2021",
    "Year": "2021"
  }
]

var plansList = [];

var Years = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var YearName = myArray[i].Year;
  if (!Years[YearName]) {
    Years[YearName] = [];
  }
  Years[YearName].push(myArray[i].PlanName);
}
myArray = [];
var result = [];
for (var YearName in Years) {
  const plansList = Years[YearName].filter(plan => {
    return plan.slice(-4) == YearName
  });
  myArray.push({
    year: YearName,
    plan: plansList
  });
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
myArray = [
 {

    "PlanName": "Plan1 - 2020",       
    "Year": "2020"
},
{
   "PlanName": "Plan2 - 2020",       
    "Year": "2020"
},
{
    "PlanName": "Plan3 - 2021",       
    "Year": "2021"
}
]

var plansList =  [];
var Years = {};

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
{ 
 var YearName = myArray[i].Year;
 if (!Years[YearName]) 
 {
   Years[YearName] = [];
 }
 Years[YearName].push(myArray[i].PlanName);
}

myArray = [];
var result = [];
for (var YearName in Years) 
{
  const plansList = Years[YearName]
                     .filter(plan => plan.slice(-4) === YearName)
                     .map(p => ({planValue: p, planName: p}));  
  myArray.push({year: YearName, plan: plansList});
}

console.log(myArray);
```